# problem binding pipe async inn custom directive input

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, directive

i have a little big problem!

i have custom directive that put hidden attribute depending of an input entrance.

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive]'
})
export class CreateTicketButtonActiveDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive);
    if (!(this.ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive === 'Administrador' || this.ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive === 'Comercial')) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'hidden', 'true');
    }
  }
}
```

This directive if working because when i hardcode the entrance it works ok like this:

```
<button [ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive]="'Administrador'"  class="col-1 add"  [ngClass]="{ addInSmall: isSmallOrXSmall() }" (click)="addTicket()">
            <span class="material-icons add-icon"> add_to_photos </span>
          </button>
```

then problem is that that string i have to take from a database.

i tried to create an observable and use pipe async but it allways takes null. the remarkable code of component:

```
export class TicketingKanbanComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  public activeUserRoleNameSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  public activeUserRoleName$: Observable<string>;

....
}

    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        const roleUid = (await 
        this.userBaseGesRoleRepository.findOneByActiveUser().toPromise()).metadata.roleUid;
        this.role = (await this.roleRespository.findOne(roleUid).toPromise()).metadata.name;
        this.activeUserRoleNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.role)
        this.activeUserRoleName$ = this.getActiveUserRoleName$();


        ....
    }


    private async getActiveUserRoleName() {
        console.log(this.role);
        this.activeUserRoleNameSubject.next(this.role);
    }


    
    private getActiveUserRoleName$(): Observable<string> {
        return this.activeUserRoleNameSubject.asObservable();
    }
```

when i pass the parameter like this:

```
      <button [ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive]="(this.activeUserRoleName$ | async )"  class="col-1 add"  [ngClass]="{ addInSmall: isSmallOrXSmall() }" (click)="addTicket()">
        <span class="material-icons add-icon"> add_to_photos </span>
      </button>
```

the directive allways recive null!

i know that if have to be something of the lifecicle but i have try all that i believe that should works its says NO NO NO to me

EDIT:

using various console.logs, i've seen that the prblem is that it throws th directive before the ngoninit  take the value from DDBB.

but i dont know how to make it before.

EDIT 2 (FIXED):

i finally make it works making the DDBB consult inside of the directive.

but i still dont if it should be possible resolve the consult of the database in the component before load the template, ecause in the constructor i cannot use async await.

Comment: I'm a little surprised it works at all. You should be getting a "cannot read properties of undefined" error: *first* you access `this.activeUserRoleNameSubject.asObservable()`, and *then* asign value to `activeUserRoleNameSubject`. At least you should reverse those two last lines of your `ngOnInit`.

Comment: you are right, i have it like you say but i  copied and paste lines a little bit caotically here and i  make a mistake. now im going to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your problem is clearly lifecycle of component and directive building.
Directive is created and takes the value from it's input `ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive` at that time, which since it's a database fetch, will most likely be null. It will continue to listen to this value, but will not execute the behaviour you want and defined in ngOnInit because this lifecycle event only happens once.

I can see at least 2 possible ways of solving this.

**First**

You can drop the use of a custom directive and rely on `[hidden]="logicHere"`.
It's not a very common practice to manipulate HTML through the use of Renderer.
It would look something like this:

```
<button [hidden]="!((this.activeUserRoleName$ | async ) === 'Administrator' ||  (this.activeUserRoleName$ | async ) === 'Comercial')"  class="col-1 add"  [ngClass]="{ addInSmall: isSmallOrXSmall() }" (click)="addTicket()">
        <span class="material-icons add-icon"> add_to_photos </span>
      </button>
```

Or just replace the logic inside hidden with a custom function.

**Second**

You can continue with your custom directive logic, but you need to change how the `@Input` is managed.
Angular has a good page explaining this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

It would turn out to be something like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive]'
})
export class CreateTicketButtonActiveDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() 
  get ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive() {
     return this._ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive; 
  };
  set ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive(ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive: string){
     this._ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive = ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive;
     this.customFunction();
  }
  private _ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive = '';
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  customFunction() {
    if (!(this._ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive === 'Administrador' || this._ticketingPrimeCreateTicketButtonActive === 'Comercial')) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'hidden', 'true');
    } else {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'hidden', 'false');
    }
  }
}
```

Here the `customFunction` is invoked each time the value of the `@Input` changes.

Answer (score 0):

another solution would have been using resolvers to delay your component.
when it hit the ngOnInit the value would be already fetched from database. Take a look to [Angular resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)